# wifi not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 but my computer did not detect any wireless connection. I decided to look for an older and more stable version. I installed Ubuntu 14.04, but it still doesn't work.

When I had Windows 10, the wireless connection was working fine.

These are the results of `sudo lshw -C network` :

```
  *-network NO RECLAMADO  
       descripción: Network controller
       producto: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       fabricante: Broadcom Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:07:00.0
       versión: 01
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:b3200000-b3207fff
  *-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:08:00.0
       nombre lógico: eth0
       versión: 07
       serie: 2c:60:0c:db:ac:9c
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 100Mbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.61 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:47 ioport:3000(size=256) memoria:b3004000-b3004fff memoria:b3000000-b3003fff memoria:90100000-9010ffff
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo lshw -C network` to your question please?

Comment: Hi Nacho,

I tried to enter that information here but it says that the comment is too long. Is there something in specific that you are looking from that format?

So I can added here

Thanks!

Comment: Add it to the question. Select edit at the bottom of your question. To format the text as code, select the text and press Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Lucho this is the information I get

```
  *-network NO RECLAMADO  
       descripción: Network controller
       producto: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       fabricante: Broadcom Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:07:00.0
       versión: 01
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:b3200000-b3207fff
  *-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:08:00.0
       nombre lógico: eth0
       versión: 07
       serie: 2c:60:0c:db:ac:9c
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 100Mbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.61 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:47 ioport:3000(size=256) memoria:b3004000-b3004fff memoria:b3000000-b3003fff memoria:90100000-9010ffff
```

Comment: Don't provide additional information as an answer. Edit it into your question instead.